# How to get the items from youtube.com/music

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api

http://youtube.com/music lists the top 100 music videos on YouTube. How do I get these with the Data API? Can't find it documented anywhere.

The page doesn't have any RSS/Atom feeds. I don't want to scrape it :/

YouTube Data API documentation:
http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the YouTube page ( http://youtube.com/music ) to which you refer gets the list video using different criteria. A good starting point to performs a search similiar is the example:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/topic-explorer

Filtering freebase topics and leaving only those related to music