# YouTube API's most_popular feed differs from YouTube website

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

As I write this, the [YouTube website](http://www.youtube.com/charts/videos_views/music) (the "YouTube 100"?) is giving me distinctly different results for "Most Viewed Videos" for this week versus the YouTube API,

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular_Music?time=this_week

How do I obtain the YouTube website's version via the API? Previous questions from others here and elsewhere don't seem to have gotten a reply from YouTube support, so I ask again.

[Is there a free unilimited API to get the top 100 billboard with Youtube music videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189523/is-there-a-free-unilimited-api-to-get-the-top-100-billboard-with-youtube-music-v)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/znCSaWqLTaQ

[How to get the items from youtube.com/music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083081/how-to-get-the-items-from-youtube-com-music)

Comment: I tried to answer your question 2 and 4